# How to instantiate .class file which i get at run time

Tags: java, object

I get a class file at runtime and I am saving it in a particular location. How can I create an object of this class:

```
Class.forName(MyDynamicClass);
```

This does not work. The class does not have any package, so how to instantiate this class ?

I just have the MyDynamicClass.class file which is in my home folder

I tried "Amir Afghani" [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320404/creating-classes-dynamically-with-java) which throws the ClassNotFound Exception.

Comment: try `Class.forName("MyDynamicClass");`

Comment: throwing classnotfoundexception, MyDynamicClass.class is saved outside the package

Comment: what about `Class.forName("packageName.MyDynamicClass");`

Comment: There is no package name for this class file

Comment: i don't have the .java file for this class .just have the .class file
"C:\...\workspace_java\Dynamictest\CrazyClassCreation.class"

Answer (score 0):

```
        ClassLoader myClassLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

         // Step 2: Define a class to be loaded.

        String classNameToBeLoaded = "MyDynamicClass";


         // Step 3: Load the class

        Class myClass = myClassLoader.loadClass(classNameToBeLoaded);


         // Step 4: create a new instance of that class

        Object whatInstance = myClass.newInstance();
```

Comment: String classNameToBeLoaded = "MyDynamicClass"; 
what should i give in place of  "MyDynamicClass", in my case "MyDynamicClass.class" is file saved in somelocation

Comment: URL myurl[] = { new URL("file:///C:/Amal/file/web/"),
        new URL("http://www.aba.com/somepath/") };
    URLClassLoader x = new URLClassLoader(myurl);
    Class c = x.loadClass("MyDyamicClass");

    Class getArg1[] = { (new String[1]).getClass() };
    Method m = c.getMethod("main", getArg1);
    String[] my1 = { "arg1 passed", "arg2 passed" };
    Object myarg1[] = { my1 };
    m.invoke(null, myarg1);

Answer (score 0):

I have tested with and without package and both cases working fine.

Below are the classes

> Default Package:

```
public class MyDynamicClass {

}
```

> Under package com.test

```
package com.test;

public class MyDynamicClass {

}

package com.test;

public class MyDynamicClassTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class clazz = Class.forName("com.test.MyDynamicClass");
            Class clazz2 = Class.forName("MyDynamicClass");


            System.out.println("clazz :: "+ clazz);
            System.out.println("clazz :: "+ clazz2);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

> ```
> Output:
>
> clazz :: class com.test.MyDynamicClass
> clazz :: class MyDynamicClass
> ```

You can call newInstance() to create object once you have class object.

How are you compiling your class? Can you make sure there is .class file exist?

Comment: In your case "MyDynamicClass" is saved in side package called "com.test" and you can see the import statement, so "com.test.MyDynamicClass" and "MyDynamicClass" are same

Comment: There are two - one with the package "com.test" and another in 'default' package.

Comment: delete "Class clazz = Class.forName("com.test.MyDynamicClass");" and "package com.test;" and run your program

Comment: forget about everything, just tell me how to create a object of a class file which i saved in "C:\MyDynamicClass.class". i get the class file at runtime i dont have the .java file for that class.

Answer (score 0):

Steps that you can try to debug:

1. Check your class path
   When you perform Class.forName("MyDynamicClass");
   It checks in your classpath for the file MyDynamicClass.class and loads it
2. When you run your program, run with **-verbose** argument
   This will help you identify how this class is searched and is loaded once you fix the class path issue
3. If you do not want to add this to your classpath, then you will most definitely have to write your own class loader (See *java.net.URLClassLoader* which provides an easier way to do this). This will allow you to put custom paths to be loaded

Comment: there is no class path , its just a file "MyDynamicClass.class" saved in one location

Comment: You should append that directory to your classpath, then try it again.

Comment: @Amal Could you please update your question with the directory structure and the steps that you are performing to do this, also What did u set as your classpath??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320404/creating-classes-dynamically-with-java
checkout "Amir Afghani" answer