# How to write my own JSON parser?

Tags: java, json

I want to write a JSON parser that parses input JSON of depth n for college assignment.
As far as I have understood, I will have to convert this JSON into `<String, Object>` map and then create classes out of it.

Is this correct? also How would I come to know exact datatypes of the values in JSON?

for ex my sample JSON sis.

`{
  “name”: “user”,
  “address”: {
    "city":"abc",
    "zip":12345
  }
}`

Then I am supposed to create a class named say User that has to fields
1. name: String 2. Adderss : Object
and Address class having city : string and zip :int with getters and setters.

Is this correct? How to dynamically create a class?
How should I start ?

Comment: Dynamically creating classes at runtime is possible, but complicated. You'd probably be better off just using `Map` and `List`.

Answer (score 0):

see this for that (not recommended): [Creating classes dynamically with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320404/creating-classes-dynamically-with-java).

Advice of @T.J.Crowder is a good one: some collection.

```
public class json_java{
Map<String,Object> values=new HashMap<String,Object>;
```

To get the type:

```
JSONObject one_object=...
Object one_value = one_object.get("city");
one_value.getClass().getName(); // => String
```